# In SQL what is the character limit

Tags: sql, webmatrix

**My Question:** In SQL; I only use SQL so I am asking about it only, what is meant by the data length?

If a column of data type nvarchar is set to length 50 (its the default value for each new column I create in WebMatrix), does that mean the 51st character would cause an error?

Comment: It means that if you try to put 51 characters into that field, you will not suceed.  By the way, sql is an acronym for Structured Query Language and does not identify any database software.

Comment: Characters, you mean letters? Does ' ' (space) count in that too?

Comment: Yes, it does. FYI, I **highly** suggest you to edit this question to improve it. Otherwise you might have difficulties asking further questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What edit should I make, can you suggest please?

Comment: I hate to say, but this is pretty easily Googleable, and a pretty basic SQL question

Comment: @AdrianWragg, that means I will first have to read what data types allow!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I think that would be a great idea, personally. You can't learn an entire subject from a Q&A site; you need to have some basic knowledge first.

Comment: Yes, I was learning some information about the SQL data types from msdn (Microsoft Developer Network). But I was not able to find how many characters can be there, I did have a look at the data size, but not the characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are stored in SQL databases generally using either a fixed length format (`char()` or `nchar()`) or a variable length format (`varchar()` or `nvarchar()`).

`char()` and `varchar()` use one byte to store each character.  The "n" prefix allows unicode characters (2-bytes wide) to be stored.  In all cases, the maximum length of the field comes between the parentheses.  **This is measured in units of characters not bytes**.  So, `varchar(2)` and `nvarchar(2)` can both store up to two characters.  The latter takes up twice as much space (for the character storage, not counting the length) as the original.

This is the maximum length of the field, so anything up to that length can be stored.  If you try to store additional characters, then the behavior may depend on the database and the operation.  You might get truncated values.  Or you might get an error.

Spaces count as characters, just as everything else does.

If you are writing the SQL yourself, then **do not use default lengths**.  Always use these constructs with an explicit length, or you might get unexpected and difficult to find errors in your code.

In general, the documentation for a specific database does a pretty good job of explaining these concepts.  I would suggest that you start there for the explanation.

Comment: As the size of a field is bytes, surely nvarchar can only store half the number of characters? So in your example, nvarchar(2) can only store one character.

Comment: @AdrianWragg . . For `nvarchar()` the length is measured in characters.  You can check, for instance, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html.  That misinformation in the comment is specifically why I wrote this answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll remove my comments; I was mis-remembering.

Comment: Everything that I need is explained well! :) Thanks, and I will try to go through the first link that you provided in comment too.

Comment: I was also confused about the misinformation and thought maybe I am slipping, but thanks to this answer.